# Asp .net dropdownlist data keep load

Tags: asp.net, postback

After I get the value show in GridView the DropDownList will contain duplicate items when I click again.

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sql = "select distinct cproject from I.dd.project";
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
       DropDownList1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
    }
    con.Close();
}

public void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sqldataadapter da = new sqldataadapter(Select * from lalala where id =    '"+dropdownlist.item.selectedvalue.tostring()+"')
   +"where A.cproject ='"+DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString()+"', con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Can you show a snippet of your view (assuming you're using MVC)? My guess is you're appending to an existing model that you're passing to the View from your Controller. If you can provide this, I think we can help :-)

Comment: Please put valid code in your question. `public void Page_Load {` is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write it as:

```
public void Page_Load
{
  if (!IsPostBack){
    string sql = "select distinct cproject from I.dd.project";
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
     DropDownList1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
    }
    con.Close();
  }
}

public void button_click
{
    sqldataadapter da = new sqldataadapter(Select * from lalala where id =    '"+dropdownlist.item.selectedvalue.tostring()+"')
   +"where A.cproject ='"+DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString()+"', con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It shows a complete answer for OP.

Comment: Code does not compile, and no explanation is given as to what the actual issue was. You should provide an explanation for the problem.

Comment: Can you point to where code compilation is a requirement to answering a question? Although, I do agree more context should have been given.

Comment: Most of the time ASP control will cause a post back. So ever time page_load calls thus it duplicate the dropdown list.
@mason

Comment: It is not a requirement, but it is preferable that code compiles. And the explanation should be in the answer itself, rather than a comment on the question.

Comment: @mason, I see - your answer is more eloquent, but downvoting everyone else's answer without providing a reason doesn't seem terribly constructive.

Comment: I am new to the stackoverflow. I doesnot know much about. Thanks for you suggestion and i am no issue with downvoting :)

Answer (score 0):

The `Page_Load` method is called each time a postback occurs (such as when you click on an ASP.NET button control). The data was already added on the first load and stored in ViewState. On the second request, it adds it again. You can detect whether you're in a postback by using the [Page.IsPostBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        // add items to drop down list
    }
}
```

---

Side note, make sure that any objects that implement the [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface are handled properly. You need to make sure they're disposed when you're done with them to avoid hard to diagnose errors. You can either call `.Dispose()` on them in a `finally` block or you can wrap them in a `using` statement. Your `SqlCommand`, `SqlConnection` (this should not be a property/field)`and`SqlDataReader`all implement`IDisposable`.

Answer (score -1):

At best-guess, without compile-able code, it looks like your Dropdown List is persisted between page loads, meaning it's never going out of context (the object remains in memory). So, it is just getting appended over and over each time there is a page load. You probably want to do a check for existing values:

```
public void Page_Load()
{
    string sql = "select distinct cproject from I.dd.project";
    con.Open();
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) {
        using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                //Have not tested the if statement... may need to correct it.  
                if(!DropDownList1.Items.Contains(dr[0].ToString())) {
                    DropDownList1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Several reasons: there's a pointless mention of MVC in the opening paragraph. The code doesn't compile. "Never going out of context" isn't clear, neither is "destructed" (those have very different meaning when it comes to code). And [DropDownList.Items.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.contains(v=vs.110).aspx) does not accept a string parameter, it accepts a `ListItem`. And even if you created a new list item and passed it in, it's probably doing a reference check, not a value check. You'd need to loop through all items to check.

Comment: Thank you - I noted I had not tested it - and I did my best given the quality of code provided by OP.

Comment: Updated the answer to remove MVC reference.

Comment: I suggest you read [Answering Technical Questions Helpfully](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) by [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) (he has the top reputation on Stack Overflow).

Answer (score -1):

I just found the solution. Put the if(!Ispostback) in the page load statement there.

Comment: If there is an existing answer that already says this, there is no need to post your own answer. Checking the checkmark next to that answer indicates it solved your issue.

Comment: maybe my internet speed slow so I didn't see the reply. Will refresh before reply next time.